# Output Gadfly Graphics and DataFrame in one SVG, PDF, etc

Tags: julia

I'm trying to create a simple report that shows some summary DataFrames along with several graphics. I can write several graphics as SVG for example, but how can I write several graphics and a small DataFrame to a single SVG, or PDF, etc.?

```
using Gadfly, DataFrames

plot1 = plot(x = rand(10), y = rand(10)) 
plot2 = plot(x = rand(10), y = rand(10)) 

draw(SVG("combined_plost", 5inch, 5inch), hstack(plot1, plot2))
```

Which outputs two plots next to each other, as desired. Now let's say I also want to include a small DataFrame with the two plots above, which contain summary information for example.  How can I do this?

Something like this is what i'm asking about:

```
df = DataFrame()
df[:vars] = collect(1:10) 

draw(SVG("combined_plots", 5inch, 5inch), vstack(hstack(plot1, plot2), df)
```

So that I can have my graphics and summary values in a single SVG, or similar format. It doesn't necessarily need to be a DataFrame, some other container or format is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [IJulia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl) to create an interactive notebook and then export it to PDF and many other formats using [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html).

You can test in:

- https://try.jupyter.org (currently has older version of Julia)
- https://juliabox.com

This example was tested in try.jupyter.org:

[image]

**Note**: I couldn't go on and export it in neither site, since converting to PDF requires **Inkscape**, which is not installed by those providers, but you can install everything locally instead.

Comment: Yeah, this is an OK solution. Thanks for your input. I was hoping to not use IJulia here, as I have a script that outputs some summary data after doing calculations (mostly graphics, but I wanted to add a summary DF). The graphics output looks great, it would just be nice to also include a DF. The combined output here could be nicely shared with others.

Comment: @JeremyMcNees I don't understand, I used a DataFrame in the example. It is converted to HTML table, it would also be output to PDF along with the graphics and whatever else you got there. I'll try to set everything up locally, so I can show you the example PDF.

Comment: I was hoping to have an automated process. My script will produce many summary outputs. I can't click download as PDF every time. Is there a way to automate to PDF conversion process?

Comment: @JeremyMcNees yes you can, as stated by the documentation of `nbconvert` (that I linked in my answer), ie. `jupyter nbconvert --to FORMAT notebook.ipynb`